# Recommendation to refactor android code

Tags: android, refactoring, listener

I'm C# programmer and pretty new to Android programming.

In case of following codes below, any recommendation to refactor?
many listener inside of listener make hard to refactor.

In C#, `async/await` can get a return value from `HttpClient` so that I can isolate json communication from logic code.

But as far as I know, android `listener` requires `final` keyword in order to send result to outside of its scope, and `final` cannot accept value after the http communication (I use [loopj httpclient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)).

Note that my app minimum requrement is API version 8.

```
            // A delete button to remove a post.
buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
// Show dialog to ask to delete.
                Dialog.ShowMessageDialog(PostViewActivity.this, getString(R.string.dialogDeletePost), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
// Async http DELETE send.
        MainActivity.HttpClient.delete(ServerUrl.QUESTION.toString() + "/" + id, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String s) {
// when result received, close current activity.
                                super.onSuccess(s);
                                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                                QuestionViewActivity.this.finish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable, String s) {
                                super.onFailure(throwable, s);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

// show yes-no dialog
public void ShowMessageDialog(Context context, String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onYesClickListener){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, onYesClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? explain that,, I cant figure out your problem. wht you want to do?

Comment: @MitBhatt // OK, what is the best way to flatten above inside-of-inside-of-inside listener logic? It mixed up view listener, dialog listener, and http listener. Or specifically, how can I isolate http communication logic from above code? I want to get simple http result like `int httpResultCode = deletePostAsync(id);`.

Comment: It depends on You.! I think You have done copy this code.. :) it ok! but Now Think your requirement. This  "inside-of-inside-of-inside listener logic" has logic of when button click it shows dialog and through that you get httpResultCode. So here If you want to remove dialog then you have only two listener,,

Comment: If I become free from my work than I'll do simple code for that and post here for you.till you can try as I say.@

Comment: My question is not solved yet. any advice will be welcomed :)